# Negative sentence of the given statement

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What should be the negative of the sentence?

***"Rakhi plays sports in the evening."***

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself? Is there something in particular you don't understand? Have you tried to find out how to change a positive sentence into a negative one?

Answer (score 1):

Since the verb is 'plays', I would say,  'Rakhi does not play sports in the evening'. [This page](http://www.whitesmoke.com/negative-sentences) gives detailed explanations about constructing negative sentences.

Comment: Why 'does not'? Can I say "Rakhi don not play sports in the evening." If not then why?

Comment: @Saksham - "Don not" isn't any kind of proper English.  Do you mean "*do* not"?  You can't say "Rakhi do not" because you have to conjugate the verb *to do* to match the subject ("Rakhi"), and the third person singular present is *does*.

Comment: @Saksham- 'Do not' is usually used with first person singular or second/third person plural. Check out these links: (http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/don-t-and-doesn-t) and (https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/dodontdoesdoesnt)